# Copy Image to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an image as a DataURL string. 
And I want to copy this image programmatically to ClipBoard.

I found two functions, but neither of them works.
Though, first function works well when you copy text - copy("Hello!","text");

PS I have a "clipboardWrite" permission.

First:

```
function copy(str, mimetype) {
    document.oncopy = function(event) {
        event.clipboardData.setData(mimetype, str);
        event.preventDefault();
    };
    document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
}
```

Second:

```
function copyImage(url){
    var img=document.createElement('img');
    img.src=url;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    var r = document.createRange();
    r.setStartBefore(img);
    r.setEndAfter(img);
    r.selectNode(img);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.addRange(r);
    document.execCommand('Copy');
}
```

Comment: possibly something to do with the mime type?

Comment: I tried various types but without any success.

Comment: You might need to encode the image then copy it.

Comment: I think at least one of them _is_ working but clipboard data is not always compatible cross-app. If I select the "google-chrome" tag above with its icon, the icon appears when I paste in Gmail (same browser) but not in TextEdit (OS X app)

Answer (score 3):

Seems this isn't possible. There has been a bug preventing it in Chrome since 2012! https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150835

Answer (score 2):

If it happens to use html2canvas this can be done like that:
This converts something with html2canvas to a canvas and then produce the image of it and then saves it to clipboard as png. For example,

HTML:
`<div id="copyToImage">Hello World!</div>`

JavaScript:

```
$("#copyToImage").click(function() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#copyToImage")).then(canvas => canvas.toBlob(blob => navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({'image/png': blob})])));
});
```

Answer (score -4):

//copy image to ClipBoard Using Java Robot

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mspaint.exe");
Thread.sleep(5000);
StringSelection x=new StringSelection("Location of Photo with format");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(x,null);
Robot r=new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(4000);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(1000);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
Thread.sleep(5000);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(5000);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTEXT_MENU);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTEXT_MENU);
Thread.sleep(1000);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(2000);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
Thread.sleep(2000);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```

Comment: Java is not javascript

Comment: Yeah, nothing to do with Chrome Extensions.